# wcin.imbue and UTF-8

Tags: c++, utf-8, g++, locale, clang++

On linux with g++, if I set a utf8 global locale, then `wcin` correctly transcodes UTF-8 to the internal wchar_t encoding.

However, if I use the classic locale and imbue an UTF8 locale into wcin, this doesn't happen. Input either fails altogether, or each individual byte gets converted to wchar_t independently.

With clang++ and libc++, neither setting the global locale nor imbuing the locale in `wcin` work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    if(true)        
        // this works with g++, but not with clang++/libc++
        locale::global(locale("C.UTF-8"));
    else
        // this doesn't work with either implementation
        wcin.imbue(locale("C.UTF-8"));
    wstring s;
    wcin >> s;
    cout << s.length() << " " << (s == L"áéú");
    return 0;
}
```

The input stream contains only áéú characters. (They are in UTF-8, not any single-byte encoding).

Live demo: [one](http://ideone.com/AX4nXc) [two](http://ideone.com/JWbbQo) (I can't reproduce the other behaviour with online compilers).

Is this standard-conforming? Shouldn't I be able to leave the global locale alone and use `imbue` instead?

Should either of the described behaviours be classified as an implementation bug?

Comment: What do you mean by "clang++" here? The compiler is irrelevant as this depends entirely on the standard library (both C and C++ parts) and the installed locale data on the machine. Did you check with both libstdc++ and libc++, or just check libstdc++ twice with two compilers?

Comment: @JonathanWakely You are right, I should have said "libstdc++ and libc++". I think I did use libc++ with clang++ but I can't check that right now. Will double-check and update as soon as I get to my machine.

Comment: OK, then I wonder if the problem is a fundamental limitation of `wcin`, in that the conversion from UTF-8 octets to `wchar_t` is done by the stdio layer, which uses the global locale not the stream's one. But it could just be a bug in libstdc++ (and maybe libc++ too), I'm not sure. Naïvely I too would expect your use of `imbue` to work.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I'm not sure how conversion via stdio could possibly work. fstream implementation uses `fread` which shouldn't do any translation.

Comment: @JonathanWakely it turns out that with libc++ *neither* branch works. I will update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you should use wcout with wcin.

Now you have two possible solutions to that:

1) Deactivate synchronization of iostream and cstdio streams by using

```
   ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
```

Note, that this should be the first call, otherwise the behavior depends on implementation.

```
int main() {

   ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
   wcin.imbue(locale("C.UTF-8"));

   wstring s;
   wcin >> s;
   wcout << s.length() << " " << (s == L"áéú");
   return 0;
}
```

2) Localize both locale and wcout:

```
int main() {

   std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "C.UTF-8");
   wcout.imbue(locale("C.UTF-8"));

    wstring s;
    wcin >> s;
    wcout << s.length() << " " << (s == L"áéú");
    return 0;
}
```

Tested both of them using ideone, works fine. I don't have clang++/libc++ with me, so wasn't able to test this behavior, sorry.

Comment: OK I know the global setlocale works with libstdc++. But why do we need to unsync with stdio in order to imbue a locale? I couldn't find anything in the standard.

Comment: The sync allows you to use cout and printf in same program.
Non-locale C streams will break the utf-8 encoding while synced with C++ stream.
That's why the second solution uses the global setlocale.

Comment: But I don't do any C stream I/O, why the unsync is still needed?

Comment: It's a default behavior to sync the streams

Comment: By default, iostream objects and cstdio streams are synchronized (as if this function was called with true as argument).
If the streams are synchronized, a program can mix iostream operations with stdio operations, and their observable effects are guaranteed to follow the same order as used in the program.

(from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/sync_with_stdio/)

Comment: Please see this: http://ideone.com/Bx48s5 Very funny, you need to unsync in order to imbue, but not in order to do the actual I/O. I now think it's a bug in libstdc++.

Comment: As I mentioned before, according to standard the call to unsync should be the first one otherwise the behavior is undefined, I'm not sure that the second call from your example actually does anything.

Comment: "If any input or output operation has occurred using the standard streams prior to the call, the effect is implementation-defined." Doess imbue count as input or output?

Comment: It's an operation that modifies the stream.

Comment: The standard doesn't use such terminology. It talks about an input or output operation. Since no input or output takes place, I'm inclined to believe imbue isn't one. Unless the standard says otherwise of course.

Comment: "You can call it reliably only before performing any operations on the standard streams." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yxhba01.aspx

Comment: Those are words of Microsoft, not of the standard. While I love Microsoft just as the next guy, they are not exactly known for their strict \dherence to the C++ standard.

Comment: You're right. It appears there is another option for libc++:
    `locale wcin_loc{wcin.getloc(), new codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>{}};`
    `locale wcout_loc{wcout.getloc(), new codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>{}};`
    `wcin.imbue(wcin_loc);`
    `wcout.imbue(wcin_loc);`


http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/89497304c877220b

However it doesn't work in ideone and clang without unsync either. It looks like standard implementation differences.

Comment: Naturally I can insert my own codecvt, the idea is that it should happen automatically...

Comment: Well, if trying to use pure imbue uproach the same code on coliru works fine without "-stdlib=libc++" (or with "-stdlib=libstdc++") and halts to work with "-stdlib=libc++". So I agree with you, it looks like the implementation bug.  However there is no hard evidence for that.

Comment: If I could up vote this 1,000 times I would. I can't believe how hard it was to find a clean answer for how to read a UTF-8 file with C++.

Thank you for this answer!

Comment: To get the above code working on windows, the locale name needs to change from C.UTF-8 to en_US.UTF8.

For example:

wcin.imbue(locale("C.UTF-8")); 

would be changed to

wcin.imbue(locale("en_US.UTF8"));